# JS - Check if this is the text I want inside this text

Tags: javascript

I wanted to do something in my code that if this text was equal to the text I wanted, do it, and if it was not equal, do it.
Now what should I define to check if the text is the same as the text I want?
As below.

```
function email(){
    let email = prompt('Enter your email!');
    let gmail = "@gmail.com";
    if (/* 
        Now I want to go here and check if the text has the "gmail" variable or not.
         */
        ) {
        alert('Successfully!. and your email is' + email);
    } else { 
        alert("I'm sorry. This email address is incorrect.")
    };
};
```

Comment: I think you're trying to check if `@gmail.com` is in `email` right? Not if it's exactly the same? In this case you can use `email.includes( gmail )` or to check if `email` ends with `gmail` : `email.endsWith(gmail)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function email(){
    let email = prompt('Enter your email!');
    let gmail = "@gmail.com";
    if (email.includes(gmail)) {
        alert('Successfully!. and your email is' + email);
    } else { 
        alert("I'm sorry. This email address is incorrect.")
    };
};

email()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
if(email.includes(gmail))
{
   //do something here
}
```

For more info check: [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)